# inject javascript to Qwebview by pressing a button outside Qwebview

Tags: javascript, html, qt, qtwebkit, qwebview

I tried running this but nothing happens.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    ui->webView->load(QUrl("javascript:alert('hello world')"));
}
```

But it works if i load javascript it from an html file.

```
<a href="javascript:alert('hello world');">Click here to say hi</a>
```

I know I can run javascript from an html file but, my question is how can i inject javascript to a webview using a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try QWebFrame::evaluateJavaScript().

Comment: thanks for the info it works. but i used  void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
  ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("javascript:alert('hi')");
}

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. You are welcome. You should mark my answer as a valid solution now so your question is shown as solved.